# Native image build failed with error: Main entry point class 'io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.MicronautLambdaRuntime' not found

Tags: micronaut, graalvm

I have a Micronaut application that runs properly in my local environment. I am now trying to build the Docker image for it.

```
D:\project\student-custom-runtime> docker build . -t student-custom-runtime
```

The build fails with the error:

```
Error: Main entry point class 'io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.MicronautLambdaRuntime' not found.
```

However, I have checked that the **Project and External Dependencies** of my project has the `micronaut-function-aws-custom-runtime` jar

This is the **build-native-image.sh** file:

```
${GRAALVM_HOME}/bin/native-image --no-server \
             --class-path student-custom-runtime-*.jar \
             -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=src/main/resources/reflect.json \
             -H:EnableURLProtocols=http \
             -H:IncludeResources="logback.xml|application.properties|.*/endpoints.json$" \
             -H:Log=registerResource \
             -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles="dynamic-proxies.json" \
             -H:Name=server \
             -H:Class=io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.MicronautLambdaRuntime \
             -H:+ReportUnsupportedElementsAtRuntime \
             -H:-AllowVMInspection \
```

Stacktrace:

```
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Main entry point class 'io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.MicronautLambdaRuntime' not found.
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:65)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:240)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:422)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:108)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

I am not sure what would be causing this error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue but with graalvm maven plugin. The main class specified is not being found.

Comment: @Sebastian unfortunately it didn't but I raised the same question on Github -> https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1558, please try the steps mentioned here and see if it works for you.

Comment: thank you for replying. Finally, I used the maven plugin and it worked by setting the start class property. Anyway, I was not able to create a native image for my spring boot application. It has still some issues that the spring team and graalvm team are working on.